# Return all json elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have some code I am trying to reverse engineer. Here is the script...

```
define(function (require) {

    "use strict";

    var $                   = require('jquery'),
        Handlebars          = require('handlebars'),
        groupAdapter      = require('adapters/group'),
        homeHtml            = require('text!tpl/Home.html'),
        groupListItemHtml = require('text!tpl/GroupList.html'),

        homeTpl = Handlebars.compile(homeHtml),
        groupListItemTpl = Handlebars.compile(groupListItemHtml);


    return function () {

        this.initialize = function () {
            // Define a div wrapper for the view. The div wrapper is used to attach events.
            this.$el = $('<div/>');
            this.$el.on('keyup', '.search-key', this.findByName);
        };

        this.render = function () {
            this.$el.html(homeTpl());
            return this;
        };

        this.findByName = function () {
            groupAdapter.findByName($('.search-key').val()).done(function (products) {
                $('.product-list').html(groupListItemTpl(products));
            });
        };

        this.initialize();

    };

});
```

...here is the template that is being used in tpl/home.html

```
<div class="topcoat-navigation-bar">
    <div class="topcoat-navigation-bar__item center full">
        <h1 class="topcoat-navigation-bar__title">Daily Comedy App</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="search-bar">
    <input type="search" placeholder="search" class="topcoat-search-input search-key">
</div>

<div class="topcoat-list__container scroller" style="top:138px;">
    <ul class='topcoat-list list product-list '></ul>
</div>
```

So...the current functionality is that a search bar is displayed on the home page, and when text is typed data from my json is displayed on the page.

What I would like to do is simply loadd all the data from my json on this initial page, rather than have the user search.

My JS stinks, so be kind! ;)

PS phonegap people might recognise this code from the EU Day.

Comment: I couldn't understand your question. You want to load the same json from the search bar to the home page? If this is what you want, why not just call the same search method at page load?

Comment: I want to get rid of the search bar all together and just load all the data in the json file on the page when the page loads.